# Changing the keys in array of objects || javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects from some api call. Each of these objects have a key named id. I want to change this id to post_id for each object in the array
The first key in each object is id, so I have accessed index 0 in the code below.

Thanks in advance.

```js
function changePostId(receivedData) {
  receivedData.forEach(obj => {
    var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    var key = keys[0].replace(/^id/, "post_id");
    tmp[key] = obj[keys[0]];  
  });
}
```

Comment: it is `obj` not `temp`.

Comment: Yes I have changed that

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Spread Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). Return the object with rest properties and `post_id` equal to `id` of the object.

```js
let arr = [
  {id:0,other:"elm 1"},
  {id:1,other:"elm 2"},
  {id:2,other:"elm 3"},
]
let res = arr.map(({id,...rest}) => ({post_id:id,...rest}));

console.log(res);
```

#### Using [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)

If you want to modify the original data you can use `delete`

```js
let arr = [
  {id:0,other:"elm 1"},
  {id:1,other:"elm 2"},
  {id:2,other:"elm 3"},
]
arr.forEach(item => {
  item.post_id = item.id;
  delete item.id;
})

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are really making things too complicated. You don't have to work with `Object.keys`, just access `.id`:

```
for(const obj of receivedData) {
  obj.post_id = obj.id;
  delete obj.id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating the keys array won't update the object itself.

What you need to do is:

1. create property `post_id` and assign the `obj.id` value
2. delete the `obj.id` property

```js
function changePostId(receivedData) {
  receivedData.forEach(obj => {
    obj.post_id = obj.id;
    delete obj.id;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

access the id key from the object and assign it to new key (post_id) and then delete the post_id.

```
receivedData.forEach(obj => {
  obj.post_id = obj.id;
  delete obj.id;
})
```